# How to import multiple csv files into Power Query Editor

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a relational database tables exported in csv files where each file has the content of one table (hospital.csv, patient.csv, admission.csv ..)

In Excel's Power Query, I can import the csv files as queries one by one using `New Query > File > Text/CSV` but I have to repeat that for each csv file which is tedious.

Those are the queries which I want to have:

[image]

If I import the entire folder `New Query > File > Folder`, I end up with one query containing the contents of each file like so

[image]

How can I split this and create automatically one query for each file so that I end up with one query per csv file (like on the 1st screenshot?)

Answer (score 0):

Each query can only create .. one query .. so the answer to your question is that you cannot do that directly with powerquery. You can create subsequent queries that reference and filter the master query, or use VBA to dynamically create the queries